# Getting error jse_cause: unknown method: Not implemented for Webdriverio touchAction and touchPerform API

Tags: webdriver, appium, webdriver-io, appium-android, android-uiautomator

**Setup configuration:**

```
uiautomator2 version : 2.35.0
appium version : 2.3.0
webdriverio version : 8.15.0
node version : 16.18.0
```

**Code block that's causing issue:**

- `touchAction` API:

  ```
  browser.touchAction([
      { action: "press", x: xStart, y: yStart },
      { action: "wait", ms: speed },
      { action: "moveTo", x: xFinish, y: yFinsh },
      { action: "release" }
  ])
  ```
- `touchPerform` API:

  ```
  browser.touchPerform([
      { action: "press", options: { x: xStart, y: yStart } },
      { action: "wait", options: { ms: speed } },
      { action: "moveTo", options: { x: xFinish, y: yFinsh } },
      { action: "release", options: {} }
  ])
  ```

**Error:**

```
VError: a BeforeAll hook errored, process exiting: node_modules/test-package/dist/test-steps.js:66: Not implemented
    at Runtime.runTestRunHooks (/tmp/scratchTyFrlT.scratch/test-packageo45mGa/node_modules/test-package/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib/runtime/run_test_run_hooks.js:23:23)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Runtime.start (/tmp/scratchTyFrlT.scratch/test-packageo45mGa/node_modules/test-package/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib/runtime/index.js:53:9)
    at async runCucumber (/tmp/scratchTyFrlT.scratch/test-packageo45mGa/node_modules/test-package/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib/api/run_cucumber.js:106:21) {
  jse_shortmsg: 'a BeforeAll hook errored, process exiting: node_modules/test-package/dist/test-steps.js:66',
  jse_cause: unknown method: Not implemented
      at getErrorFromResponseBody (file:///tmp/scratchTyFrlT.scratch/test-packageo45mGa/node_modules/test-package/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:194:12)
      at NodeJSRequest._request (file:///tmp/scratchTyFrlT.scratch/test-packageo45mGa/node_modules/test-package/node_modules/webdriver/build/request/index.js:164:23)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at async Browser.wrapCommandFn (file:///tmp/scratchTyFrlT.scratch/test-packageo45mGa/node_modules/test-package/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/shim.js:72:29)
      at async Browser.wrapCommandFn (file:///tmp/scratchTyFrlT.scratch/test-packageo45mGa/node_modules/test-package/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/shim.js:72:29),
  jse_info: {},
  cause: [Function: ve_cause]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a bug in latest version of Appium driver `uiautomator2`, as I am also seeing this issue.  Solved by installing older version of `uiautomator2`, as described in:
[Uiautomator 2 causing issues with «driver.swipe()»](https://discuss.appium.io/t/uiautomator-2-causing-issues-with-driver-swipe/40741). This post mentions using v2.29.4, I've found up to v2.29.11 works.  My experiments reveal duping bug in v2.30.0 - latest (v2.35.0).

Steps to fix, on your Appium server:

```
# Uninstall your latest version of Appium driver
appium driver uninstall uiautomator2
# Install specific version of Appium driver, that doesn't exhibit this issue.
appium driver install uiautomator2@2.29.11
```